# How do I create an empty file, without line breaks?

Tags: batch-file, echo

This is the command I am using in my batch file.

```
echo.>"E:\data\text.txt"
```

This successfully creates the `text.txt` file in the destination folder, but inside the `text.txt` file, a new line break is added by default.

How do I create an empty file without line breaks?

Comment: All lines Windows text files end with a Carriage Return and Line Feed pair, there is nothing wrong with that. In this particular case, it is being introduced by the `echo` command. If you don't want it, don't use `echo`, use ```CD.>"E:\data\text.txt"``` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cd.>"E:\data\text.txt" helped me. It just created an empty file without any line breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
type nul > E:\data\text.txt
```

The result will be a file, having file size zero (so not even an empty line).